# How to retrieve data in a specific format from a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table = table1, the data in this table is as follows

```
user_id    user_name  count_activity  activity_name
1            ravi         2                login    
2            rahul        5                logout
1            ravi         6                send mail 
3            vinod        10               update authrization
2            rahul        50               delete authrization
```

And i want to use this data to make 3 views like this.

```
First View                   Second View               Third View

Activity        Details     Activity     details     Activity       details 
user             ravi       user          rahul       user           vinod
login            2          logout         5          update auth..   10
send mail        6          delete auth..  50
```

Comment: show what you have tried for this.

Comment: Which attribute is your primary key?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data from database this is the query:

```
select user_name, activity_name activity, count_activity as Details from <tablename> order by user_name
```

You can add where clause to get data as per your requirement.

Comment: not group by, there are no aggregates, but maybe just an ORDER BY to keep common users activity / details together.

Answer (score 0):

```
select activity_name as Activity,count_activity as Details  from table where user_name ='ravi';
```

View1

Same goes for other views